# I have a 3D printer and I cant figure out how to digitally reverse the x and y axes

Tags: stepper-motor, reverse-polarity

There are red yellow gray and green wires, in that order.

Comment: Too many factors. Not enough info. Colour codes without knowing what they mean are useless.

Comment: You should provide more information about the motor in question.  There are apparently numerous color codes for stepper motors.  If you meter continuity between the four wires you may find that they connect to two coils and you may be able to switch the coils with eachother or switch polarity.  If it connects with a 4 pin connector, check that the connector is not backwards.

Comment: what does `reversing digitally` mean? ... does it mean that you want to use your fingers?

Comment: If these are the small motors common to Prusa-ish machines, reversing the connector happens to reverse the motor. Have you tried that? Otherwise, you'd need to either modify the firmware or somehow introduce an inverter on the DIR pin of the driver. More detail would obviously be needed in that case.

Comment: Your question might have an answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14136/how-to-determine-proper-stepper-polarity

Answer (score 4):

Since these are quadrature controlled stepper motors, inverting direction **only** required swapping   wire in each pair polarity.

Since each winding wires will be adjacent pairs, to change both polarities;

1. Change 12,34 to 21,43 or
   **Rd Yw,  Gy Gn**  to **Yw Rd,Gn  Gy**

The home command will rezero the counter steps. (now in the desired  direction)

Reversing the connector 1234 to 4321 **will also invert direction AND swap XY** or rotate the position 90 deg which for a square gantry is OK.